# SQL: Get last 3 posts of each theme

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, blogs

I have a blog SQL system with 'posts' table like this (id, theme, title, content, created).

I would like to get the last 3 titles of each post theme, to display in a table, but I didn't get it.

I tried this SQL code:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
GROUP BY theme
ORDER BY created DESC
LIMIT 0,3
```

But this gives me the last 3 posts of the table!!!

Can you please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean be the last 3 titles? Is there another table that is joined with this table? If so post its structure.

Comment: Is `created` a `datetime` field? Or simply a string representation of a `datetime` value?

Comment: Indeed, created is a SQL-timestamp value type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Josvic Zammit's answer is in parts right (+1 from me) but you don't have to perform the query per theme. This is a way you can do it in MySQL, although it would surely be easier to "perform the query per theme" in PHP or whatever.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT
IF(@prev != sq.theme, @rownum:=1, @rownum:=@rownum + 1) AS rownumber, @prev:=sq.theme, sq.*
FROM
(
    SELECT
    *
    FROM
    posts
    , (SELECT @rownum:=0, @prev:=0) r 
    ORDER BY theme, created DESC
) sq
) q
WHERE q.rownumber <= 3
```

Note that I unfortunately can't test it right now, but it should work. Also note, that this query might be slower than performing a simpler query per theme.

Comment: Thank you for your answer tombom. Indeed, I tried your code, and it works! I will implement your solution right now because I haven't a lot of rows, but surely, when number of rows increase, I'll use Josvic Zammit's code for its easiness and speed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You're doing some parts right, but in others you're not understanding the use of the `GROUP BY` clause.

The `LIMIT` above works on the whole query results. Besides you need an aggregate function for the `GROUP BY` to be applied on, e.g. `SUM`, `AVG`, etc. You cannot simply `SELECT *` and expect grouping by `theme`.

The `GROUP BY` returns one row per item you're grouping by, for instance, the *latest*, and not three rows.

Therefore you need to perform the query **per theme** you're grouping by, but in this case you don't need to group by at all. Write a loop that executes this query for each theme you require:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
WHERE theme = "your-theme"
ORDER BY created DESC
LIMIT 0,3
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanation about the `GROUP BY` work. Indeed, when not specifying the `LIMIT`, it gives last post for all posts themes.